# how can i get a data frame with margin values of my population?

Tags: r, dataframe, margin, weighted-average, calibration

I keep on getting this error: Error in array (x, c(length(x), 1L), if (!is.null(names(x))) list (names (x), 'data' must be of a vector type, was 'NULL':

```
library(icarus)
Demo$poids2 <- calibration (data=Demo$poids2, margin Matrix=margins, colWeights="poids",method="raking",calib Tolerance =0 .0000001,maxIter=500,popTotal = nrow(Demo$poids2))
```

i want to have a new data.frame where margins values were in.